# Replacing :id from routes without breaking the convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, convention

I just replaced the :id on the resource routes in rails 3 for a hash generated. I'm annoyed by the fact that I'm writing less conventional code (e.g. a link_to edit_user_path(@user) is now written as link_to '/users/#{@user.user_hash}'). So I'm wondering, is therea smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    user_hash
  end
end
```

and `edit_user_path(@user)` will work properly for you