# Multiple, custom URLs for Rails 3 resources without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my app I've got various resources that I want to access via multiple URLs. For example, an invoice can be accessed via:

```
/invoices/:id
```

By the issuer of the invoice, and also via:

```
/pay/:payment_key
```

By the payer.

The latter URL does not require authentication (hence the secrefied payment_key).

The issue is how to get automatic URL helper methods for the custom URL. Usually you could use `to_param` to customize the resource URL (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146286/replacing-id-from-routes-without-breaking-the-convention)), but that's not adequate in this case because I still want to retain the default resource URL.

If I create the helper methods by declaring a named route:

```
/pay/:payment_key, :as => :invoice_payment
```

Then I would expect `invoice_payment_url(invoice)` to include `invoice.payment_key` but it doesn't. Rails uses the invoice ID instead (similar to the behaviour reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326483/rails-3-resource-routing-without-an-id))

This seems like it's broken.

So I've been defining the url helpers for this resource manually.

```
def invoice_payment_path (invoice)
  url_for :controller => "invoices",
  :only_path => true,
  :action => "pay",
  :payment_key => invoice.payment_key
end

def invoice_payment_url (invoice)
  url_for :controller => "invoices",
  :only_path => false,
  :action => "pay",
  :payment_key => invoice.payment_key
end
```

Wondering if there is a DRYer way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

RESTful is about resources. So are you sure the "payment" and "invoice" resources the same thing in your system? To me, it is more like a system design issue than a routing issue.

Another thought is using nested resources. You can view either "/payments/:id/invoices" or "/invoices/:id/payments", both make sense to me.

Yan

Comment: I agree, but id OP still wants to follow this route `invoice_payment_path(:payment_key => invoice.payment_key)` would work.

Comment: @gzbigegg Thanks. Agree that they are different resources, but that isn't the issue. I still want to create the payment from the invoice and need the url helper to give me a URL based on the invoice model. The issue is what key is used to identify the resource. I need two for security reasons.

Comment: @Rubish Okay, but that would shift the responsibility for creating the correct URL to the caller. That feels icky to me.